# Remove guest checkout option

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

What's the simplest solution for removing the guest checkout option for Sylius.

Change the security.yml to make it require logged in user? (this doesn't redirect with a message to say register or login)

Customise the controller (uses the updateAction on the resource controller which i'd prefer to leave as is as it's likely to update in the future)

Any other options? There used to be a config option but that seems to be unavailable

Comment: Could you override the template and remove the guest checkout link?

Comment: I don't think there is a guest checkout link, it just starts the process for you. Any creates an anonymous customer not linked to a user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably make an access control based on the `/checkout/.+` path, so that you cannot access those endpoints as a guest. That would be enough.